# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of Null using Nude.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, nude.js

what i Need

- i need to scan and check image is nude or not.
- i  using nude.js for image detection problem im facing after including nude.js when page is loaded  the error appear in console.

nude.js

```
(function(){

var nude = (function(){
    // private var definition
    var canvas = null,
    ctx = null,
    resultFn = null,
    // private functions
    initCanvas = function(){
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        // the canvas should not be visible
        canvas.style.display = "none";
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        b.appendChild(canvas);
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    },
    loadImageById = function(id){
        // get the image
        var img = document.getElementById(id);
        // apply the width and height to the canvas element
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        // reset the result function
        resultFn = null;
        // draw the image into the canvas element
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    },
    scanImage = function(){
        // get the image data
        var image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
        imageData = image.data;

        var myWorker = new Worker('worker.nude.js'),
        message = [imageData, canvas.width, canvas.height];
        myWorker.postMessage(message);
        myWorker.onmessage = function(event){
            resultHandler(event.data);
        }
    },
```

abc.html

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img").load(function(){

nude.load('testImage');
nude.scan(function(result)
{

if(!result) alert("no nude"); 
else
alert("nude)"); });
 });
 });
```

Error

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
  canvas.width = img.width; // line 28
```

Comment: that means `document.getElementById(id)` isn't finding anything.

Comment: Your code calls `nude.load()`, which isn't defined in the code shown in your question. Assuming it ends up in the `loadImageById()` method, that method doesn't actually test whether the specified element exists. Are you sure you have the correct element id?

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `nude.init();`. I faced the same problem today. Even if nude.js is calling itself a nude.init() after registering the nude object to the window - but it doesn't seem to happen.
Side Note: the `canvas` itself is null. The error comes from the `canvas`, not from the `img`.

Include jQuery and call `$(document).ready(...)` and do a `nude.init();` in there.